# Sum up numeric lead part of strings

Tags: excel

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4.
350      mac      360     jan
500      jan      200     mac
```

This is excel.. How to sum up in just one excel formula like you want a total for jan which is 860 and mac as well..
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this formula.

```
=SUM(IF(RIGHT(SumRng,3)=A$1,VALUE(LEFT(SumRng,LEN(SumRng)-4)),0))
```

`SumRng` is a named range containing all your items to be summed. In your example it may have been like A2:D2.

`A1` contains the search text. In your example it's either "jan" or "mac". Note that it's not case sensitive. "Jan" and "Mac" will be included in the sum.

I tested the formula in Excel 365. However, in older versions of excel you may have to enter it as an array formula, confirming it with <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hi, I tried the formula and got error. I also tried to modify and it resulted to 0. Am I right to change only the SumRng of the formula given above? I don't understand -4.

Comment: It's better to name the range in your workbook, not replace the range name in the formula. But you can do that, too provided you replace all instances of the name with the same address and handle $-signs consistent with your copying intentions. `Left(SumRng, Len(SumRng) -4` creates a LeftString of the cell's value which is 4 characters shorter than the original. That is 3 characters for "jan" plus one space. So, "360 jan" becomes "360" by removing the 4 last characters.

Answer (score 1):

I used an Excel table, and named it `tbl`.

If you have Excel O365, you can try:

```
=SUM(IF(H2=INDEX(tbl,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tbl)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(tbl)-1,2,1)),INDEX(tbl,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tbl)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(tbl)-1,1,1))))
```

The `INDEX` functions create two arrays, each one column less than the original table.  When we see a match, we return the cell offset one to the left of the matched cell, giving you the totals you want.

[image]